# Google Wallet Object API access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, android-pay

I would like to get access for **Wallet Object API**. I have registered for it using the following the link -> https://support.google.com/wallet/objects/contact/WOB_interest?rd=1

But, unfortunately I got a gmail response like this "....*Since Google Wallet Objects is not a payment solution, we will not be able to onboard you*."

- I do not have any issuer account. Anyone please suggest, how to access the Merchant Console.
- Is the **API service** available **outside US** ? Has any developer **outside US** created and saved the objects in Google wallet ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like google thinks you are asking for the wrong api for your intents with the product. Check out this page https://developers.google.com/wallet/which-api to make sure you are looking at the right api.

Comment: The API that we have registered for is "Save to Google API for the web". We are planning to implement google 'wallet to wallet' payment.

Comment: The  "Save to Google API for the web" is designed to let costumers have a token that identifies them for promotions of your service.
 The transaction process handling should be done with https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/